# How come my email link in drupal footer message doesn't work?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

This is what I have typed in the footer message section from the site configuration, sight information page:

`Copyright Sage 2010 | Contact Us: < a ="mailto:admin@mysite.org" >admin@mysite.org< / a> | < a="www.mysite.org/contactoptions" >other contact options< / a>`

However, when i click on the links nothing happens. I was told all I need to do is set input format to 'Full HTML' in drupal to make that work. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be missing the 'href' attribute. Also, lose the spaces. It should be:

```
Contact Us: <a href="mailto:admin@mysite.org">admin@mysite.org</a>
```

Something similar works fine on my drupal site.

Comment: Thanks! I need to take an html refresher.